# TransactionTooLarge Package manager has died

Tags: java, android

I am getting reports of an exception happening at the line that says "progress.show()"

`R.string.loading_details` = "loading details"

Anyone know what the problem is?

```
@Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress = new ProgressDialog(context);
            progress.setMessage(act.getString(R.string.loading_details) + "...");
            progress.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    task.cancel(true);
                }
            });
            progress.show();

            super.onPreExecute();
        }
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Package manager has died at
>   android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getActivityInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:261)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3472)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:336)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:241)
>   at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:337) at
>   android.app.ProgressDialog.onCreate(ProgressDialog.java:198) at
>   android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:363) at
>   android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:264) at
>   com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx$a.onPreExecute(SourceFile:80) at
>   android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587) at
>   com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.mymethod(SourceFile:59) at
>   com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxActivity$8.onItemClick(SourceFile:355)
>   at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:308)
>   at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1476)
>   at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3497)
>   at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4814) at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
>   android.os.TransactionTooLargeException at
>   android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method) at
>   android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.getActivityInfo(IPackageManager.java:2059)
>   at
>   android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getActivityInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:256)
>   ... 24 more

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61150
Maybe this?